# Create dynamic frame from S3 bucket AWS Glue

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, etl, aws-glue, aws-glue-connection

**Summary:**
I've got a S3 bucket which contains list of JSON files. Bucket contains child folders which are created by date. All the files contain similar file structure. Files get added on daily basis.

**JSON Schema**

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField("main_data",StructType([
        StructField("action",StringType()),
        StructField("parameters",StructType([
            StructField("project_id",StringType()),
            StructField("integration_id",StringType()),
            StructField("cohort_name",StringType()),
            StructField("cohort_id",StringType()),
            StructField("cohort_description",StringType()),
            StructField("session_id",StringType()),
            StructField("users",StructType([StructField("user_id",StringType())]))
        ]),
    )]
    )),
    StructField("lambda_data", StructType([
            StructField("date",LongType())
        ]))
    ])
```

**Question**
I am trying to create dynamic frame from options where source is S3 and type is JSON. I'm using following code however it is not returning any value. Where am I going wrong?

**Script**

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from functools import reduce
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame

## @params: [JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)


    df = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
        connection_type = 's3',
        connection_options={'paths':['Location for S3 folder']},
        format='json',
        # formatOptions=$..*
        )
        
    
    print('Total Count:')
    df.count()
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if your Glue Role has access to the S3 bucket,

Also in connection_options add

`"recurse" : True`

Comment: Hi Vikram, there was a spelling error in my script smh. All working as expected now.

Also, I was missing recurse so added that in.  Thanks for your help.